# Добавление страницы в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть готовый сайт на wordpress, к нему надо допилить 1 страницу, сверстал, подключил футер, хедер, вопрос, как добавить её в саму систему вордпресса, создал новую страницу через админку, а что делать дальше, чтоб оно выводило, то что я сверстал?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать [шаблон темы](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) или [шаблон страницы](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B#.D0.A8.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BD.D1.8B_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.86) или аналогично шаблон записи (с ВП 4.7)

Answer (score 0):

В редакторе созданной страницы можно указать какой шаблон будет использоваться для ее вывода. Ячейка "Page Attributes" - поле "Template", где необходимо указать сверстанную страницу шаблона